# Looping over a pipeline parameter - what is the point?

Tags: powershell, loops, for-loop, pipeline

In a [tutorial made by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/ps101/09-functions?view=powershell-7.2#error-handling) there is a code snippet similar to the following (edited the original to reduce distraction):

```
function Test {
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        [string[]]$Params
    )

    process {
        foreach ($Param in $Params) {
            Write-Output $Param
        }
    }
}
```

In all previous examples however, the `process` block itself was already used as a loop body. To my understanding, the following simplified code should be equivalent:

```
function Test {
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        [string[]]$Params
    )

    process {
        Write-Output $Params
    }
}
```

Indeed, no matter what I pipe to it, the results are the same. However, the fact that it appeared in a first party tutorial makes me believe that there might be some actual reason for using the loop.

Is there any difference in using one pattern over the other? If yes, what is it? If no, which one is the preferred one?

---

Just in case my simplification is off, here is the original example:

```
function Test-MrErrorHandling {

    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory,
                   ValueFromPipeline,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [string[]]$ComputerName
    )

    PROCESS {
        foreach ($Computer in $ComputerName) {
            Test-WSMan -ComputerName $Computer
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `[string[]]$Params` is an array - that is, multiple items are passed at once.  In the example you link to, it uses `Test-WsMan`, where the `-ComputerName` parameter takes _one_ computer name at a time, so if you passed an entire array, it would fail, hence the loop.

Comment: The common use cases are: `SomeCommandThatOutputsComputerNames | Test-MrErrorHandling` and `Test-MrErrorHandling -ComputerName 'Computer1', 'Computer2'`. In the first one, the `foreach` loop isn't necessary, because pipeline input gets unrolled automatically and passed one-by-one to the `process` block. In the 2nd case there is no unrolling, so the `process` block receives the whole array and you need `foreach` to process the elements one-by-one.

Comment: Created a document issue for this: [`#8946` Use Singular Parameters](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/8946)

Comment: @iRon I don't see an issue with ms docs in this case I think it's a perfectly valid example. it's actually surprising `Test-WSMan` doesn't take `string[]` already

Comment: @Santiago, I was just thinking this over myself. I agree, it is a valid example, but it is not a good example in a sense that it should require some explanation *why* you do this (**what is the point?**) *especially for an advanced function*. Basically you unroll the pipeline items which is *not always* desired.

Comment: @Santiago, found a related github issue: [`#4242` Consistently document a scalar -InputObject parameter as an implementation detail or make item-by-item processing cmdlets explicitly iterate over collection](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4242)

Comment: @iRon yes in that case I totally agree with you. It is confusing for newcomers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The Point

There is quiet a difference in what you passing on to the next [cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/cmdlet-overview) in the [pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines) (in your case `Test-WSMan`):

```
function Test1 {
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        [string[]]$Params
    )
     process {
        foreach ($Param in $Params) {
            Write-Output ('Param: {0}, ToString: {1}, Count: {2}' -f $Param, "$Param", $Param.Count)
        }
    }
}

1,2,@(3,4) |Test1
Param: 1, ToString: 1, Count: 1
Param: 2, ToString: 2, Count: 1
Param: 3, ToString: 3, Count: 1
Param: 4, ToString: 4, Count: 1
```

```
function Test2 {
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        [string[]]$Params
    )

    process {
        Write-Output ('Param: {0}, ToString: {1}, Count: {2}' -f $Params, "$Params", $Params.Count)
    }
}

1,2,@(3,4) |Test2
Param: System.String[], ToString: 1, Count: 1
Param: System.String[], ToString: 2, Count: 1
Param: System.String[], ToString: 3 4, Count: 2
```

In other words, in the second example, you actually pass a string array (`[String[]]`) to `Test-WSMan`. As [`Test-WSMan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.wsman.management/test-wsman) actually requires a single string (`[[-ComputerName] <String>]`), PowerShell will conveniently [Type Cast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion) the string array (`String[]`) to a single string type (`String`).
Note that in some instances this might go wrong as in the second example if you e.g. (accidently) force an array (`@(3,4)`) in the pipeline. In that case multiple items in the array will get joined and passed to the next cmdlet.

#### Use Singular Parameter Names

In general, it is (strongly) recommended to [Use Singular Parameter Names](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/strongly-encouraged-development-guidelines#use-singular-parameter-names) which usually also implies that you expect a single `String` for each pipeline item (e.g. a `$ComputerName` at the time):

> Avoid using plural names for parameters whose value is a single element. This includes parameters that take arrays or lists because the user might supply an array or list with only one element.
>
> Plural parameter names should be used only in those cases where the value of the parameter is always a multiple-element value. In these cases, the cmdlet should verify that multiple elements are supplied, and the cmdlet should display a warning to the user if multiple elements are not supplied.

This would mean for your second example:

```
function Test2 {
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        [string]$Param
    )

    process {
        Write-Output $Param
    }
}
```

Where your own (rather than the invoked `Test-WSMan`) cmdlet will than produce the error:

```
1,2,@(3,4) |Test2

Test2: The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the
command either because the command does not take pipeline input or
the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters
that take pipeline input.
```